# unresolved external symbols by typedef

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I got error unresolved external symbols when calling a class constructor. The constructor is declared as:

```
// #include header files

class Constant
{
    Constant(boost::uint16_t featureID, boost::uint32_t featureValue);
}
```

The definition is in another .cpp file:

```
// #include header files

Constant::Constant(boost::uint16_t featureID,  boost::uint32_t featureValue)
{
    m_featureID = featureID;
    m_featureValue = featureValue;
}
```

The source/header files of Constant class can be built successfully. But when I called Constant() from another file, it got error.

```
Constant dfObj1 = Constant(0, 1); // error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall pClickDLL::Constant::Constant(unsigned short, unsigned long)
```

The weird thing is when I changed `boost::uint16_t` to `unsigned short`, `boost::uint32_t` to `unsigned int` in source/header files of Constant class, it goes no problem.

I guess the error is result from some mistakes of type redefintion, like `boost::uint16_t` in the header file means a type but another type in source file (for example, `boost::uint16_t` could means `unsigned short` in header files, but `unsigned int` in source files, maybe). This could happen when I include different header files, and the header files typedef differently, in source/header files of Constant class. But I don't get why it happens here as I already put namespace before type. `boost::uint16_t` should always means same type in source/header files of Constant class. Isn't it?

**UPDATED**: The problem is I use different boost library for two projects. I used boost 1.42 for the project of Constant class, and boost 1.53 for the project of calling file.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding from scratch?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "like boost::uint16_t in the header file means a type but another type in source file"? Do you mean you typedefed uint16_t or boost::uint16_t?

Comment: @Cameron: yep, I always `rebuild` project.

Comment: @Borgleader: for example, `boost::uint16_t` could means `unsigned short` in header files, but `unsigned int` in source files.

Comment: Compile each of the 2 files(say `Constant.cpp` & `Main.cpp`) with `/P /d1PP`. You will get 2 files `Constant.i` and `Main.i`. Open them - they are the preprocessed files - search for `unint16_t` in both files - you will be able to see what they are defined to & why.